# boot from USB drive on windows 7

Tags: usb

I have a USB drive that I downloaded Linux onto but when I try to boot it onto my Windows 7 computer it doesn't show up in the boot menu. I have used LinuxLive USB creator to configure the flash drive, but it still does not show up

Comment: try unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

When starting your computer, You'll probably need to push some button before Windows boots. I can't day for sure which button, as this varies from one computer to another.

If you have a manual for your computer, perhaps you could try looking to see if there's anything helpful. If you don't have one, try searching the web for your specific make/model, to see if a digital version exists. You should be able find your model # by pressing <kbd>winlogo</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, entering `dxdiag`, and pressing enter.